# CSS - Sizing images within a container row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate the sizing proportions of three images in a row as per a PSD file I've been given and I can't quite get them sized correctly. Here's how they should look (images don't need to be identical nor does font size - its the image size in the row that's important) -

[image: PSD file]

And this is my coded version so far -

[image]

Here's the code for the section

```css
    /* SKELETON.CSS   */

/* Grid
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.column,
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* For devices larger than 400px */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0; }
}

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%; }
  .column,
  .columns {
    margin-left: 4%; }
  .column:first-child,
  .columns:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; }

  .one.column,
  .one.columns                    { width: 4.66666666667%; }
  .two.columns                    { width: 13.3333333333%; }
  .three.columns                  { width: 22%;            }
  .four.columns                   { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .five.columns                   { width: 39.3333333333%; }
  .six.columns                    { width: 48%;            }
  .seven.columns                  { width: 56.6666666667%; }
  .eight.columns                  { width: 65.3333333333%; }
  .nine.columns                   { width: 74.0%;          }
  .ten.columns                    { width: 82.6666666667%; }
  .eleven.columns                 { width: 91.3333333333%; }
  .twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }

  .one-third.column               { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .two-thirds.column              { width: 65.3333333333%; }

  .one-half.column                { width: 48%; }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns          { margin-left: 8.66666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two.column,
  .offset-by-two.columns          { margin-left: 17.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-three.column,
  .offset-by-three.columns        { margin-left: 26%;            }
  .offset-by-four.column,
  .offset-by-four.columns         { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-five.column,
  .offset-by-five.columns         { margin-left: 43.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-six.column,
  .offset-by-six.columns          { margin-left: 52%;            }
  .offset-by-seven.column,
  .offset-by-seven.columns        { margin-left: 60.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eight.column,
  .offset-by-eight.columns        { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-nine.column,
  .offset-by-nine.columns         { margin-left: 78.0%;          }
  .offset-by-ten.column,
  .offset-by-ten.columns          { margin-left: 86.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eleven.column,
  .offset-by-eleven.columns       { margin-left: 95.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-third.column,
  .offset-by-one-third.columns    { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column,
  .offset-by-two-thirds.columns   { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-half.column,
  .offset-by-one-half.columns     { margin-left: 52%; }

}


/* Base Styles
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* NOTE
html is set to 62.5% so that all the REM measurements throughout Skeleton
are based on 10px sizing. So basically 1.5rem = 15px :) */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }
body {
  font-size: 1.5em; /* currently ems cause chrome bug misinterpreting rems on body element */
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Raleway", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222; }


/* Typography
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300; }
h1 { font-size: 4.0rem; line-height: 1.2;  letter-spacing: -.1rem;}
h2 { font-size: 3.6rem; line-height: 1.25; letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h3 { font-size: 3.0rem; line-height: 1.3;  letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h4 { font-size: 2.4rem; line-height: 1.35; letter-spacing: -.08rem; }
h5 { font-size: 1.8rem; line-height: 1.5;  letter-spacing: -.05rem; }
h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.6;  letter-spacing: 0; }

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  h1 { font-size: 5.0rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 4.2rem; }
  h3 { font-size: 3.6rem; }
  h4 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
  h5 { font-size: 2.4rem; }
  h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; }
}

p {
  margin-top: 0; }


/* Links
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
a {
  color: #1EAEDB; }
a:hover {
  color: #0FA0CE; }


/* Buttons
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.button:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
.button:focus,
button:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-color: #888;
  outline: 0; }
.button.button-primary,
button.button-primary,
input[type="submit"].button-primary,
input[type="reset"].button-primary,
input[type="button"].button-primary {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0; }
.button.button-primary:hover,
button.button-primary:hover,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="button"].button-primary:hover,
.button.button-primary:focus,
button.button-primary:focus,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="button"].button-primary:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1EAEDB;
  border-color: #1EAEDB; }


/* Forms
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea,
select {
  height: 38px;
  padding: 6px 10px; /* The 6px vertically centers text on FF, ignored by Webkit */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
/* Removes awkward default styles on some inputs for iOS */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none; }
textarea {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px; }
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #33C3F0;
  outline: 0; }
label,
legend {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 600; }
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0; }
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline; }
label > .label-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal; }


/* Lists
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
ul {
  list-style: circle inside; }
ol {
  list-style: decimal inside; }
ol, ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0; }
ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;
  font-size: 90%; }
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }


/* Code
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
code {
  padding: .2rem .5rem;
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  font-size: 90%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  border-radius: 4px; }
pre > code {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: pre; }


/* Tables
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
th,
td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0; }
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0; }


/* Spacing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
button,
.button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }
input,
textarea,
select,
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem; }
pre,
blockquote,
dl,
figure,
table,
p,
ul,
ol,
form {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem; }


/* Utilities
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.u-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-max-full-width {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-pull-right {
  float: right; }
.u-pull-left {
  float: left; }


/* Misc
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
hr {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }


/* Clearing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

/* Self Clearing Goodness */
.container:after,
.row:after,
.u-cf {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }


/* Media Queries
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/*
Note: The best way to structure the use of media queries is to create the queries
near the relevant code. For example, if you wanted to change the styles for buttons
on small devices, paste the mobile query code up in the buttons section and style it
there.
*/


/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}

body {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

section#welcome {
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

section#welcome div.row {
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#welcome h4 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  line-height: 5px;
}

section#welcome p {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}


/* centering an image within a column */

section#welcome .four {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 50px;
}

#welcome h3 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 60%;
  left: 60%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

section#welcome img {
  display: block;
}

#welcome .images {
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <h4>WELCOME TO FEATURE MEDIA</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel ex nisl. Vestibulum vitae ultricies nisl. Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque
          facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor. Suspendisse nec venenatis nisi. Phasellus sodales viverra ante quis efficitur. Pellentesque quis orci mi. Phasellus tempus, sapien ut luctus pellentesque, lacus risus accumsan lorem, in porta urna tellus
          ac nibh. Nunc varius elit non diam vehicula aliquet. In eget urna id orci molestie pulvinar. Integer quis risus eu erat iaculis aliquet ut at eros. Etiam feugiat, ante vel molestie finibus, lacus urna pharetra leo, ut lobortis massa lectus quis
          lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus turpis sagittis sapien vulputate sagittis. Nunc ac velit sollicitudin, consequat arcu ac, tincidunt risus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="hrindeximages">
    <div class="images row">
      <div class="four columns">
        <div id="video">
          <h3>VIDEO</h3>
          <img src="https://freephotos.cc/#!" alt="Video" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="four columns">
        <div id="blog">
          <h3>BLOG</h3>
          <img src="images/blog.jpg" alt="blog" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="four columns">
        <div id="faq">
          <h3>FAQ</h3>
          <img src="images/faq.jpg" alt="FAQ" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How do I get the images better proportioned within the section as per the PSD file?

Comment: What if you add `width: 100%` to your `section#welcome img` rule?

Comment: I've also made an snippet out of your code, edit it and add a link the framework you use and to your images, so we can get a real working sample

Comment: @LGSon Are there set margin/border rules for columns? I can't seem to get the images to re-size and I wonder if the skeleton grid is prohibiting this?

Comment: Can't say until you made the code sample properly working. Note, that is the minimum effort when asking for help. If you do, more experienced users will pay attention  and you'll get much more qualified answers...and if you check the ones given, you understand what I am talking about

Comment: @LGSon  Fair point. I'm still trying to get my head around the code snippet thing.

Comment: Yeah...understand that can be a challenge, and that's why I made this one for you :)

Comment: Check this, it help you how/what you can do with the snippets: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @LGSon Thanks, I've added the skeleton framework.

Comment: @LGSon I'm not sure how to show the images as they're saved on to my computer but the frame/outline gives the right idea - I think the main issue is around the margin/borders around the columns which aren't allowing the images to push out further into the space.

Answer (score 1):

increase the height and width of images according to the required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would do well to swap to actual table displays - given that your classes are already named .row .column, etc. it seems like a natural choice. You don't have to use an actual  tag but use the `display:table` CSS

Here's how I would structure the CSS to be very flexible so that you can tweak proportions easily:

Outside `display:table` wrapper

Contains a `display: row`

Row contains 3 `display: column` divs.

I see there's also some alignment issues in your version, and this would resolve that easily as well, since you can stick a `vertical-align: middle` and `text-align: center` on the cells to have the text nice and centered.

Then set the images as the backgrounds for the cells, and adjust the cell sizes and margins as needed.

Comment: So, how do I amend my code to put this into effect?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use width of the window as unit `width: 30vw` and `height: 20vw`, therefore you will always have same effect, images will scale with the window.

2) You can use images as backgrounds for your divs, it will be easier to position everything.